# Extraction of version end date in JIRA

Tags: postgresql, jira

Is it possible to create a query to a JIRA host database (Postgres) in order to extract the end date of a particular version in a project?

For example, Let's say I have software project 1 (SW1) which contains three versions(iterations) namely, V1, V2, and V3.  I am interested in writing a script which will periodically hit the Postgres database and extract the end-dates that have been set for V1, V2 and V3 within SW1.

The goal here is to be able to periodically monitor these values and notify someone when a manager/admin changes the end-date (huge NO-NO).

I've tried the Plugenta audit log plugin, and even corresponded with the developer, who indicates that logging version end-date modifications is not currently possible with their tool.

Comment: So the question is what's the name of the table(s) and column(s) where this data is stored?

Answer (score 1):

This will list the releasedates for the projectversions of a project with pname = SW1:

```
SELECT pv,vname, pv.releasedate 
FROM projectversion pv, project p
WHERE p.pname = 'SW1' and
    pv.PROJECT = p.ID
```

Comment: This is an explanation of how to extract the END date, rather that the START date.  I was able to pull this info from the Postgre db and can even do the same via the REST API, but it's not the particular data that I'm interested in finding.  It's START DATE that I need to access.